# Can anyone explain me each line of the below given code?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
if(str.contains(keyword))
        {
            String cline = str.split(keyword)[1];
            String [] allwords = cline.split(" ");
            String data1 =  allwords[1];
            String data2 = allwords[2];
            String data3 = allwords[3];
            String data4 = allwords[4];
            System.out.println(rollno+" "+data1+" "+data2+" "+data3+" "+data4);
        }
```

I just want to know about this two Lines

line no 3 : what is happening there
line no 4 : and what is happening there

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Doy you know what the `split` function does? Try experimenting and toying with it a little. And use a debugger to step through the code you show, to see the result.

Comment: no sir i don't know about split function

Comment: Then I suggest you go to [the Oracle documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/) and look for it, and read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) is javadoc for `split`.

`String cline = str.split(keyword)[1];`

This line splits the String by supplied keyword, and extracts second token from it. 
E.g. if String is "This is an example" and keyword is "is" then value of `cline` would be "an example".

`String [] allwords = cline.split(" ");`

This line splits the string by `space` and stores the resulting tokens into `allwords` String array.
E.g. if String is "This is an example" then value of `allwords` would be ["This", "is", "an" , "example"].

Comment: You should put that javadoc link **first** and explain to him that the **first** thing to do is always always look out for javadoc; instead of asking other people to explain stuff that is documented over and over already.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for the input, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Then you deserve an upvote; although answering such low quality questions is always ... well, tricky business. You see, as soon as this one gets closed (and it will be most likely be closed), I will put a delete request for it. So chances are, that this question ... and any answer will vanish at some point.

Comment: Fine, I will refrain from answering such questions then :)

Comment: All I am saying is: dont surprised when such questions go away quickly. On the other hand, they attract a lot of answers, so to have any "chance" for upvotes, you need to deliver great quality. Which means to invest a lot of your time. So, it is about balancing cost and revenue ,-)

Answer (score 0):

split will split the string by a token and return an array.
The [] operator returns the value of the array in the specific place.
so:

```
"a,b".split(",")[0] --> a
```

read this:
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Split method splits your string by the given character and returns an string array where each item is one piece of your original string.

This is:

Original String:
"My String"

Splitted by " "
item0: My
item1: String

Splitted by "t"
item0: My S
item1: ring

if you add [number] after it then you keep just the item in the number position

Answer (score 0):

- the 3rd line you splited your string based on the keyword found and took the  second, token  it's exactly like doing it like this

  String[] p = str.split(keyword);
  String cline = p[1]
- the 4th line you just repeated the process above on the "cline" String and this time you splitted using a space .

Answer (score 0):

String cline = str.split(keyword)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java);
Line3: str.split creates an array of String by separating **str** by character 'keyword' and store its second element (String) in cline String reference.
Line4: creates another array of String by separating **cline** by character ' '.
            String[] allwords = cline.split(" ");
For more information on split see [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)